# KendoUI window pop up error when closing the window

Tags: kendo-ui

I just need a little help here about displaying KendoUI window.
My situation is I have a button that will call the window. At first click of button, the window dialog will appear but after closing the window by clicking the 'x' button I can't make it appear again by pressing the same button. 
I don't know where's my error.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".test").click(function (){
        $("#window").kendoWindow({
            actions: ["Refresh","Maximize","Minimize","Close"],
            draggable: true,
            height: "300px",
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: "Purchase Order Supplier Detail",
            width: "500px"
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div id="window" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
<input type="button" class="test" value="test" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put kendo window out of button click like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".test").click(function (e) {
                $("#window").data("kendoWindow").open();
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        $("#window").kendoWindow({
            actions: ["Refresh", "Maximize", "Minimize", "Close"],
            draggable: true,
            height: "300px",
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: "Purchase Order Supplier Detail",
            width: "500px",
        });

});
</script>

<div id="window" style="display:none;"></div>
<input type="button" class="test" value="test" />
```

Div style is `"display:none;"` insted of `"visibility: hidden;"`.